# Typescript: Generic class type inference

Tags: typescript, class, generics, inference

This following seems quite simple but I am not sure what is causing the error. I've been looking around for quite awhile but I can't seem to find an answer.

```
class MyClass<T > {
  property: T = 5 // Error Here: Type '5' is not assignable to type T
}

const tester = new MyClass<number>() // OK

const numberValue: number = tester.property // OK
const stringValue: string = tester.property // Error as expected
```

I thought T would be inferred as number from 'property'. I feel like used to work in the past but I am not sure.

[Typescript playground with examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20MyClass%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20property%3A%20T%20%3D%205%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20tester%20%3D%20new%20MyClass%3Cnumber%3E()%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20numberValue%3A%20number%20%3D%20tester.property%0D%0Aconst%20stringValue%3A%20string%20%3D%20tester.property%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass2%3CT%20extends%20object%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20property%3A%20T%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass3%3CT%20extends%20number%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20property%3A%20T%20%3D%205%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

---

**Update**

These definitions also have the same errors.

```
class MyClass<T extends number> {
  property: T = 5 // Error Here: Type '5' is not assignable to type T
}

class MyClass<T extends object> {
  property: T = {} // Error Here: Type '{}' is not assignable to type T
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should never have worked.  Whatever you write in the definition of a generic class or method has to be valid for *all* possible values of `T` for which the class or method might be used.  The assignment `property: T = 5` is not valid if someone does `new MyClass<string>()` so that `T` is `string`.  Inference only occurs when you *use* a generic class or method.

Comment: What if the definition was `class MyClass<T extends number> { property: T = 5 }` instead? This gives the same error.

Comment: `T` could be a subtype of `number` (e.g., a union of literal types such as `0 | 1`); then `5` would not be a `T`.